# Order by in ng-repeat Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Inside ng-repeat, I am trying to order by a specific attribute that I get from an array other than the one I am using in ng-repeat, here is my code :

```
<tr ng-repeat="ft in ftListe | orderBy:'ProjectName'">
<td>{{projets[$index].ProjectName}}</td>
<td>{{task[$index].TaskName}}</td>
<td>{{ft.Datefeuillestemps | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
<td>{{lecollaborateur[$index].NomCollaborateur}}</td>
<td><center>{{ft.TempsPasse}}</center></td></tr>
```

I want to order by 'ProjectName', I am new to Angular and I couldn't find the solution to this.

Comment: In your controller, you should build a richer object array that contains all of the properties you need. I.e. objects inside ftListe contain that sort property you need. It will also be more efficient.

Comment: @EdSpencer   Thank you, I will try this

Comment: When you say "order by a specific attribute that I get from an array other than the one I am using in ng-repeat", you mean you want to do something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/1yhRh2uxhadYrujFrcmj?p=preview) ?

Comment: @JeanJacques in this case my array is "projects" from which i display the name of the project and this is what i want to order by but since my loop is on ftListe I don't have access to the attribute "ProjectName" , I think your solution might work for me